# In semi-supervies learning, is "low density separation" the same thing as "pseudo-labelling"?

Tags: svm, semi-supervised-learning

I'm looking into the different methods of semi-supervised learning.

In the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) page, one of the methods described is called "low-density separation", where we attempt to minimize this loss function: [image: loss function]

Now, if I understand correctly:

1. The first term is the [hinge loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss) on the labeled data points,
2. the second term is simple L2 regularization, and
3. the third term is hinge loss on the unlabeled data points, where each unlabeled data is assigned a label corresponding to the model's classification for it (so negative f(x) is multiplied by y=-1, so it's effectively the absolute value of f(x)).

So, my question is - is this the same as [pseudo-labeling](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-explanation-of-semi-supervised-learning-and-pseudo-labeling-c2218e8c769b), just for an SVC? If not, how is it different (maybe the regularization is not simply L2, or something else that I'm missing)?